# Automatically moving overlapping features using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.4, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1. I make a map. I am have two shapefiles: one polyline and one polygon. The polyline is a road and polygon is a building.

The shapefiles overlap. I want to automatically resolve the overlapping features. I want to make a "After" picture.

If polygon is placed at the center of the line, it doesn't matter which direction it moves. You only need to move to either side. I want to moving distance is likely to be 15m-20m away from the road. The building should be located only near the road as shown.

I wonder if ArcGIS can automatically shift buildings by road.

I don't have programming skills. However, the GIS program is well used.I hope to solve this problem with ArcGIS.

How to automatically move overlapping features?

[image]

The above figure is one line and the figure below is three lines. The three lines mean the center line of the road and the two outside mean the width of the road

Comment: Welcome to [gis.se].  Please follow the [tour] to learn how to ask a detailed question to attract good answers.  Please tell us what you've tried so far and what type of solutions you're open to.  That is, do you have programming skills?  Or are you after and "out of the box" solution?  This type of problem could likely be solved using python and cursors.  How much do you want to move the features?  How far away from the lines can the polygons be? Can they be touching at all?

Comment: I agree that there is enough info here.  OP has added info as well.  It's an interesting question.  It should stay open @Fezter

Comment: @ilmare do you have Advanced License?

Comment: @BERA yes, i have

Comment: An error occurs: Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 20, in <module> File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6560, in AddJoin raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open polygon_lyr Failed to execute (AddJoin).

Comment: You should not post questions/comments as answers. Im guessing you have not changed this line to match your data: `polygon_fc=r'C:\TEST.gdb\Sample_points_buffer'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159771)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script below use [Near](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool to calculate distance and angle from polygon centroids to nearest line and then move them either closer or further away depending on the specified desired distance. Create a File Geodatabase and import the shapefiles and use as inputs in script.

You can execute the code in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/saving-loading-and-recalling-at-the-python-window.htm) in ArcMap.

```
import arcpy,math
#Inputs, change paths and fc names to match your data
polygon_fc=r'C:\TEST.gdb\Sample_points_buffer'
line_fc=r'C:\TEST.gdb\Line'
#Output, change path (and fc name if you want)
output_polygon_fc=r'C:\TEST.gdb\Sample_points_buffer_near'
#Desired distance from polygon centroids to nearest line. Change
desired_distance=200

temp_points=r'in_memory\points'

def bearing_to_radians(bearing):
    return math.radians((450-bearing)%360)

#Create centroid points, calculate near distance and angle and join this to polygons
arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(in_features=polygon_fc, out_feature_class=temp_points)
arcpy.Near_analysis(in_features=temp_points, near_features=line_fc,location=True, angle=True, method='PLANAR')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=polygon_fc, out_layer='polygon_lyr')
arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view='polygon_lyr', in_field='OBJECTID', join_table=temp_points, 
                        join_field='OBJECTID')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='polygon_lyr', out_feature_class=output_polygon_fc)

#Move the polygons
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(output_polygon_fc,['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y','points_NEAR_DIST','points_NEAR_ANGLE']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        newx=row[0]+(row[2]-desired_distance)*math.sin(bearing_to_radians(row[3]))
        newy=row[1]+(row[2]-desired_distance)*math.cos(bearing_to_radians(row[3]))
        row[0]=newx
        row[1]=newy
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

How to create a File Geodatabase and import shapefiles:

[image]

Comment: An error occurs : ---

Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 15, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2483, in FeatureToPoint     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset C:\TEST.gdb\Sample_points_buffer does not exist or is not supported.   ---             

The path of the data is exactly the same.

Comment: You need to change the paths to match your data. If you have shapefile inputs i would export them to a file geodatabase and use as inputs.

Comment: I'll try again.

Comment: An error occurs : --- Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.-----

Comment: If you add the output polygon to arcgis, do they have the columns 'points_NEAR_DIST' and 'points_NEAR_ANGLE'?

Comment: No they have. have columns: 'building01', 'points_FID', 'points_OBJ', 'Points_ORI',  'points_NEA', 'points_N_1', 'points_N_2', 'points_N_3', 'points_N_4'

Comment: Looks like you are still working with shapefiles (the columns names are truncated). Like i said i Think you should import the shapefiles into a File Geodatabase Before running the script and the output should also be in the FGDB. How to create a FGDB: (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/create-file-geodatabase.htm) How to import shapefiles to the FGDB: (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-geodatabase.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well now. We get good data and information thanks to lots of attention. Now I will to study more. Thanks again.